# Pytest logging ignores dependency warnings

Tags: python, pandas, logging, pytest

I have a simple `python` script that leads to a `pandas` `SettingsWithCopyWarning`:

```py
import logging

import pandas as pd


def method():
    logging.info("info")
    logging.warning("warning1")
    logging.warning("warning2")
    df = pd.DataFrame({"1": [1, 0], "2": [3, 4]})
    df[df["1"] == 1]["2"] = 100


if __name__ == "__main__":
    method()
```

When I run the script, I get what I expect

```
WARNING:root:warning1
WARNING:root:warning2
main.py:11: SettingWithCopyWarning:  ...
```

Now I write a `pytest` unit test for it:

```py
from src.main import method


def test_main():
    method()
```

and activate the logging in my `pytest.ini`

```yaml
[pytest]
log_cli = true
log_cli_level = DEBUG
```

```
========================= 1 passed, 1 warning in 0.27s =========================

Process finished with exit code 0

-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:main.py:7 info
WARNING  root:main.py:8 warning1
WARNING  root:main.py:9 warning2
PASSED                                                                   [100%]
```

1. The `SettingsWithCopyWarning` is counted while my `logging` warnings are not. Why is that? How do I control that? Via a configuration in the `pytest.ini`?
2. Even worse: The `SettingsWithCopyWarning` is not printed. I want to see it and perhaps even test on it? How can I see warnings that are generated by dependent packages? Via a configuration in the `pytest.ini`?

Thank you!

Comment: This is in the warnings summary collected and prints at the end of the tests progress logs. Are you disabling that in your pytest.ini?

Comment: `SettingWithCopyWarning` isn't logged, just printed to stdout, so logging configuration won't change that. You can use `-s` to dump stdout to terminal immediately in pytest.

Answer (score 0):

All log warnings logged using the pytest live logs feature are done with the [standard logging facility](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#module-logging).

Warnings done with the [warnings facility](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#module-warnings) are captured separately in pytest by default and logged in the warnings summary after the live log messages.

To log warnings done through [warnings.warn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn) function immediately they are emitted, you need to inform pytest not to capture them.

In your `pytest.ini`, add

```
[pytest]
log_cli = true
log_level = DEBUG
log_cli_level = DEBUG
addopts=--disable-warnings
```

Then in your `tests/conftest.py`, write a hook to capture warnings in the tests using the standard logging facility.

```py
import logging

def pytest_runtest_call(item):
    logging.captureWarnings(True)
```